# How to add remove data function of Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I creating chat system by `React` and `Firebase`.
The data of chat stystem is managemented by `Firebase RealTimeDatabase`.
Now site here
URL: https://react-chat-b0e8a.firebaseapp.com/
Github: https://github.com/kaibara/React-chat

I trying to create data remove function.
However, I could not find an element to put in `child()`.
Because, I can't use `remove()` code.

I called firebase documentation and thought about implementing the delete function using `update ()` and `set ()` etc.
However, since `child ()` can not be specified, none of them could be used.

Would you like to share how to identify `child()` in Firebase RealtimeDatabae or implement data deletion function?

Now codes here.
`App.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { firebaseApp,firebaseDB } from './firebase/firebase'
import ChatMessage from './components/ChatMessage'

const firebaseDB = firebase.database()
const messagesRef = firebaseDB.ref('messages')

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text : "",
      user_name: "",
      messages : []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
      messagesRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        const m = snapshot.val()
        console.log({m})
        let msgs = this.state.messages
        msgs.push({
          'text' : m.text,
          'user_name' : m.user_name
        })
        this.setState({
          messages : msgs
        })
      })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="MessageList">
          <h2>メッセージログ</h2>
          {this.state.messages.map((m, i) => {
            return <ChatMessage key={i} message={m}/>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

`ChatMessage.js`

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import { firebaseDB } from '../firebase/firebase'

const firebaseDB = firebase.database()
const messagesRef = firebaseDB.ref('messages')

class ChatMessage  extends Component {
  onRemoveClick(){
    console.log(messagesRef.child(key))
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="Message">
        <p className="MessageText">{this.props.message.text}</p>
        <p className="MessageName">by&nbsp;{this.props.message.user_name}</p>
        <button className="MessageRemove" onClick={this.onRemoveClick}>削除</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChatMessage
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use the `remove()` function?

> The simplest way to delete data is to call remove() on a reference to
>   the location of that data.
>
> You can also delete by specifying null as the value for another write
>   operation such as set() or update(). You can use this technique with
>   update() to delete multiple children in a single API call.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data

In order to get the key, every time a child is added, you'll have to store the keys in a data structure alongside some reference to the message for later usage. On your `child_added` event handler, you can get it in your callback through `snapshot.key`.

In your remove message event handler, retrieve the correct key from your data structure and call this:

```
messagesRef.child(key).remove()
```

Considering your current implementation, add the `key` value to the message object. In your App `componentWillMount()` method:

```
msgs.push({
   'text' : m.text,
   'user_name' : m.user_name
   'key': snapshot.key
 })
```

In your ChatMessage `onRemoveClick()` method:

```
 messagesRef.child(this.props.message.key).remove()
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting carefully.   
The reason why I decided to implement the delete button is because I wanted to learn not only React's study but also Firebase's study and database operation. 
I implemented it according to your suggestion, but `this.props.message.key` was not loaded with` onRemoveClick`. So I am currently asking how to solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861345/how-to-read-props-on-event-on-react If you know, please cooperate.

Comment: that happens because the method is not binded to the correct `this` context. You'd have to call `this.onRemoveClick = this.onRemoveClick.bind(this)` in the ChatMessage constructor. However, you should adapt this solution into the one proposed in the other thread.

Comment: Thank you for adding comments. My problem was solved by your comment. Thank you very much.