# How to read props on event on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I creating chat system by `React` and `Firebase`.
The data of chat stystem is managemented by `Firebase RealTimeDatabase`.
Now site here
URL: https://react-chat-b0e8a.firebaseapp.com/
Github: https://github.com/kaibara/React-chat

I'm trying to implement the delete button, but I do not know how to make the child component `event` read the parent component`this.props`. 
As a solution to this, I was thinking to have `this.props` read in front of `render`.
But I do not know how to do it. 
Can you share the solution to this problem in the following code?

`App.js` - parenet component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { firebaseApp,firebaseDB } from './firebase/firebase'
import ChatMessage from './components/ChatMessage'

const messagesRef = firebaseDB.ref('messages')

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text : "",
      user_name: "",
      messages: []
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    messagesRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      const m = snapshot.val()
      let msgs = this.state.messages
      msgs.push({
        'text' : m.text,
        'user_name' : m.user_name,
        'key': snapshot.key
      })
      console.log({msgs})
      this.setState({
        messages : msgs
      })
      console.log(this.state.messages)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="MessageList">
          <h2>メッセージログ</h2>
          {this.state.messages.map((m, i) => {
            return <ChatMessage key={i} messages={m} />
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

`ChatMessage.js` - child component

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import { firebaseDB } from '../firebase/firebase'

const messagesRef = firebaseDB.ref('messages')

class ChatMessage  extends Component {
  onRemoveClick(){
    messagesRef.child(this.props.messages.key).remove()
    //　I want to load `this.props.messages.key` here
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="Message">
        <p>{this.props.messages.key}</p>
        <p className="MessageText">{this.props.messages.text}</p>
        <p className="MessageName" style={user}>by&nbsp;{this.props.messages.user_name}</p>
        <button className="MessageRemove" onClick={this.onRemoveClick}>削除</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ChatMessage
```

Please lend me your knowledge.
Thank you.

Comment: pass the removeClick as props and implement removeClick in App component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Implement the handler in your parent component and pass the reference down to child component has props

implement `onRemoveClick()` in **App** component and pass the handler refrence in `props'  to **ChatMessage** component.

**App component:**

```
 deleteMessageHandler = (key) =>{
    const messages = [...this.state.messages];
    messages = messages.splice(key,1);
    this.setState({messages:messages});
  }
```

**ChatMessage:**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="MessageList">

          {this.state.messages.map((m, i) => {
            return <ChatMessage key={i} messages={m} deleteMessageHandler={this.deleteMessageHandler}/>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**Note:** Don't use the index of the map has a key to the components in the map, its an antipattern, it should be proper unique id's.

Comment: Thank you for  commenting carefully. 
Understanding of delivery of props has deepened. I solved this problem by the solution at the following URL.　https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854542/how-to-add-remove-data-function-of-firebase-realtime-database　I appreciate your cooperation for my question.

Comment: Even though you solved the problem with my suggestion, you should still have your handler within the parent component so that you can manage state (and consequently, the UI) in the same place. In the`deleteMessageHandler()` method, just add the `remove()` call. Then, in your button, change it to `onClick={() => this.deleteMessageHandler(this.props.messages.key)}`

Comment: Happy to help 